# Generate sequence # in Hive Select Query

Tags: hiveql

How can i generate a select query in a way that i can select 5 columns and assign a unique row # for each of those rows. 
e.g. I have a table A as 
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4

Desired OUTPUT from Query: 
row_id, Col1, Col2, col3, col4

where row_id ranges from 1 till total # of rows.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `row_number` function.

```
select (row_number() over()), Col1, Col2, col3, col4 from table_name
```